# A mistake in the code for drawing a line segment in a triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I think that this post should be discarded quickly.  I have been reluctant to post it. (The code for this post is similar to the code that I posted about labels for nodes not being at the same distance from points.)  I draw triangle ABC. I put point S halfway from A to B. I want to put a point T on BC so that the line through S and T is 30 degrees below the horizontal line through S.  In the code, I issue the command `\path[name path=ST] (S) --++ (-30:5);` to do this. I get a line through S and C.  If I replace `-30` with `-90`, I get the same picture!  What is wrong with the code?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate[label=225:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=90:$B$] (B) at (60:6);

%These commands position vertex C, label it C, and positions the label southeast of the vertex.
\path[overlay,name path=horizontal] (A) -- ++(10,0);
\path[overlay,name path=BC] (B) -- ($(B)!2!75:(A)$);
\path[name intersections={of= horizontal and BC, by=C}];
\coordinate[label={[blue]-45:$C$}] (blah-blah) at (C);


%This command draws the triangle.
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

%This command draws the line segment from the midpoint S on AB to a point T on BC.
\coordinate (S) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
\path[name path=ST] (S) --++ (-30:5);
\path[name intersections={of= ST and BC, by=T}];
\draw[dashed] (S) -- (T);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try adding `draw` to your `\path` commands so you can see what is or is not happening.

Comment: Do you want `T` to be on the line `BC` or on `AC`? From your picture I think you probably mean `AC` but in your code you ask for `BC`. The problem when you use `-90` is that the line `ST` does not intersect the line `BC`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to see what happens if you use `\draw[blue, name path=ST] (S) --++ (-30:5);` instead of `\path[name path=ST] (S) --++ (-30:5);`

[image]

The line is too short and doesn't intersect `BC`. Just make it longer:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate[label=225:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=90:$B$] (B) at (60:6);

%These commands position vertex C, label it C, and positions the label southeast of the vertex.
\draw[green,overlay,name path=horizontal] (A) -- ++(10,0);
\draw[red, overlay,name path=BC] (B) -- ($(B)!2!75:(A)$);
\path[name intersections={of= horizontal and BC, by=C}];
\coordinate[label={[blue]-45:$C$}] (blah-blah) at (C);


%This command draws the triangle.
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

%This command draws the line segment from the midpoint S on AB to a point T on BC.
\coordinate[label=above left:S] (S) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
\draw[blue, name path=ST] (S) --++ (-30:15);
\path[name intersections={of= ST and BC, by=T}];
\draw[dashed] (S)  -- (T) node [above right]{$T$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had supposed that the line through S and T would intersect BC.  Oops!  Maybe, to my chagrin, I should keep the post.  The common-sense advice to use `\draw` instead of `\pat` to see what is going on may be helpful to others.